# Check input that belong to Fibonacci numbers in Python

Tags: python

I would like to ask how can I retrieve out the list of fibo list and then check whether does the input value by the user is inside the fibo list.

```
    a , b = 1, 1
while num <= sys.maxint:
    fibo == a , b = b, a+b
    if num == (b +a+b):
        print "It is a Fibonacci number"        
        break
    else:
        print "It is not a Fibonacci number"
        break
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python)? Don't they give you enough information to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I did.. But I dont really understand...

Answer (score 9):

Using a [more sophisticated Fibonacci number test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers), you could use

```
def is_fibonacci(n):
    phi = 0.5 + 0.5 * math.sqrt(5.0)
    a = phi * n
    return n == 0 or abs(round(a) - a) < 1.0 / n
```

(This is probably the most efficient way to determine whether a number is a Fibonacci number, and it is most probably not the intended solution to your homework.  I just included this answer for future reference.)

Comment: I wanted to know a name for this test. I found it as the Möbius test, from [Michael Möbius](https://web.archive.org/web/20190807010928/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s005910050048). [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190807010735/https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/41-1/komatsu.pdf) is  a discussion of the interval. Some Stack Exchange links - [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/823247/674126) [link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10002/674126).

Answer (score 5):

A pythonic one-liner

```
def is_fibonacci(n):
    return n >= 0 and (n==0 or sqrt( 5*n*n - 4).is_integer() or sqrt( 5*n*n + 4).is_integer())
```

Comment: I don't know why this is not upvoted! This code is awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a not very efficient solution - using the close formula is more efficient (see [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472128/check-input-that-belong-to-fibonacci-numbers-in-python/7472371#7472371)), but you can do this:

```
def fibs():
    a,b = 0,1
    yield a
    yield b
    while True:
        a,b = b,a+b
        yield b

n = int(raw_input("please, enter a number "))
for fib in fibs():
  if n == fib:
    print "your number is a Fibonacci number!"
    break
  if fib > n:
    print "your number is not a Fibonacci number!"
    break
```

The `fibs` generator gives you the list of Fibonacci numbers. You can go through the list, and every number you can check if it's equal to the one the user entered (in which case you're done), or if it's bigger than the one the user entered (and also in this case you're done).

I hope this is useful, at least to understand Python generators.

Comment: Thank you MarcoS! It really help me alot! Can I ask what if we dont use the def or the yield, will the codes still work? I tried but not really.

Comment: If you don't use the `yield`, then you don't get a Python generator, so the for loop does not work. Also, you remove the `def`inition  of `fibs` the code will not work any more. So, answer to your question is "if you remove `def` or `yield` the code will no longer work". But why would you want to remove them?

Comment: Erm, I want to try out other ways. Maybe like this:

Comment: import sys
#User input a number
num = int(raw_input("Input a Number:"))

a,b = 1, 1
if (a , b == b, a + b):
    True
else:
    False

while num <= sys.maxint:
    
    if num == True:
        print "It is a Fibonacci number"        
        break
    else:
        print "It is not a Fibonacci number"
        break

Comment: well, you're free to experiment other ways ... and then playing with a debugger you can figure out what happens :)

Comment: Thanks MarcoS, But can you help me with this? I dont understand why the output isnt correct:

import sys
#User input a number
num = int(raw_input("Input a Number:"))

a,b = 1, 1
if (a , b == b, a + b):
    fibo_num = True
else:
    fibo_num = False
while num <= sys.maxint:
    
    if fibo_num = True:
        print "It is a Fibonacci number"        
        break
    else:
        print "It is not a Fibonacci number"
        break

Comment: Well, there are a few things that look strange. First of all: what is `if (a , b == b, a + b):` supposed to do? I suggest that you read the Python documentation and see how `if` statements work.

Comment: hmm.. Can I ask you what is the yield means? Is it like a object to store data? Then why must fib > n, to print not fib number?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to read the manuals :) A good explanation of yield is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained). Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))

A = [0, 1]

for i in range(2,720):

    A.append(A[i-1]+A[i-2])

bool=False

for i in range(2,720):

    if x==A[i]: 

        bool=True
        break

if bool==True:

    print "Found,Index is:",i+1
else: 

    print "Not Found"
```